# Using the Spread Operator in querySelector how to prevent specific elements in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Here I create a Spread Operator with the query selector and want to colour all elements white except the  tag, in h1 I want to apply another colour, so here I also applied white colour in h1, so how do I prevent  from inheriting white colour? So here I applied the query selector only in div and p tags, but not in h1, so how do I prevent h1 from being white?
[image]

```
  export default function App() {
  const allElements = [...document.querySelectorAll("div", "p")];
  allElements.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element);
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF";
    element.style.color = "#fff";
  });
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="heading">Heading</h1>
      <div>__________________</div>
      <p className="paragraph">paragraph</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply css to parent div, it will automatically apply the styles to children as well. If you want specific elements to not have that style, you will need to override them by giving some styles. Like below

```
export default function App() {
  const allElements = [...document.querySelectorAll("div, p")];
  allElements.forEach((element) => {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF";
    element.style.color = "#fff";
  });
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="heading" style={{color: 'initial'}}>Heading</h1>
      <div>__________________</div>
      <p className="paragraph">paragraph</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or you can just give it stylesheet file if you don't want inline.

```
.heading { color: initial }
```

Answer (score 0):

the query selector is selecting the <div className="App">, you are applying style on <div className="App"> which makes all child components inherit the style. Hence, making your <h1> white too. I suggest you could use a state to change the style of  whichever div or p tags u want. In the code snippet below, you would use setWhiteColor function to change the color of the <div> and <p> to white. This is the react way of doing this.

```
const [color, setColor] = useState(false);

const setWhiteColor = () => setColor("white");

return <div className="App">
  <h1 className="heading">Heading</h1>
  <div style={{color: color}}>__________________</div>
  <p style={{color: color}} className="paragraph">paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can i give condition inside forEach loop because I want that queryselector by destructuring